# Парсер сайта на Delphi

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте.
Есть парсер для БК Марафон. 
Он ищет определенный результат в сетах(теннис) на live ставках.
Поиск происходит через определенный промежуток времени, при нахождении результата он сигнализирует о нем и выводит результат в окошке, и далее этот матч при последующих поисках не участвует. НО как только появляется новый матч или заканчивается уже идущий поиск начинается заново по всем играм, снова сигнализирует о найденных(ранее) играх и т.д.
Суть в том что при новом поиске(начале/окончании матча) найденные результаты показываются каждый в отдельном окне, и порой это долгий процесс.
Подскажите как можно вывести результаты всех найденных матчей(в которых имеется искомый  результат) в одном окне и добавить их в исключение при следующем поиске?

```
unit Parser;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, OleCtrls, SHDocVw, ActiveX, XPMan, StrUtils, mmsystem,
  ExtCtrls, Menus;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    BtnStart: TButton;
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    Memo3: TMemo;
    XPManifest: TXPManifest;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    EditInterval: TEdit;
    Label2: TLabel;
    BtnLoad: TButton;
    BtnStop: TButton;
    Timer: TTimer;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    MainMenu: TMainMenu;
    N1: TMenuItem;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    procedure Delay(const AMilliseconds: Cardinal);
    function ParseStr(str, sub1, sub2: string): tstrings;
    procedure BtnLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BtnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BtnStopClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure N1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Pars;
    procedure Search;
    procedure TimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var MainForm: TMainForm;
    Date: string;
    Used: array [0..1000] of boolean;
    Kol,KolOld: integer;

implementation

var Count: integer;
{$R *.dfm}
// процедура задержки
procedure TMainForm.Delay(const AMilliseconds: Cardinal);
var SaveTickCount: Cardinal;
begin
 SaveTickCount := GetTickCount;
 repeat
   Application.ProcessMessages;
 until
 GetTickCount - SaveTickCount > AMilliseconds;
end;

procedure TMainForm.N1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.Terminate;
end;

// поиск последнего вхождения
function PosR2L(const FindS, SrcS: string): Integer;
 function InvertS(const S: string): string;
   var i, Len: Integer;
   begin
     Len := Length(S);
     SetLength(Result, Len);
     for i := 1 to Len do
       Result[i] := S[Len - i + 1];
   end;
var ps: Integer;
begin
  ps := Pos(InvertS(FindS), InvertS(SrcS));
  if ps <> 0 then
    Result := Length(SrcS) - Length(FindS) - ps + 2
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

// извлечение текста между тегами
function TMainForm.ParseStr(str, sub1, sub2: string): tstrings;
var
  st,fin:Integer;
begin
  Result:=TStringList.Create;
  repeat
    st:=Pos(sub1, str);
    if st > 0 then begin
      str:=Copy(str,st+length(sub1),length(str)-1);
      st:=1;
      fin:=Pos(sub2,str);
      Result.Add(Copy(str,st,fin-st));
      str:=Copy(str,fin+length(sub2),length(str)-1);
    end;
  until st<=0;
end;

// процедура перевода в HTML-код
function WB_GetHTMLCode(WebBrowser: TWebBrowser; ACode: TStrings): Boolean;
var ps: IPersistStreamInit;
    ss: TStringStream;
    sa: IStream;
    s: string;
begin
  ps := WebBrowser.Document as IPersistStreamInit;
  s := '';
  ss := TStringStream.Create(s);
  try
   sa := TStreamAdapter.Create(ss, soReference) as IStream;
   Result := Succeeded(ps.Save(sa, True));
   if Result then ACode.Add(ss.Datastring);
  finally
    ss.Free;
  end;
end;

// Старт
procedure TMainForm.BtnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
var str:string;
    i: integer;
begin
   for i:=0 to 1000 do used[i]:=False;
   Timer.Interval:=StrToInt(EditInterval.Text);
   Timer.Enabled:=True;
end;

// поиск и очистка исходного кода страницы для нахождения счета
procedure TMainForm.Pars;
var str:string;
    i: integer;
  var Opt: OleVariant;
begin
  Opt:=2;
   WebBrowser1.Refresh2(Opt);
   Memo3.Clear;
   // извлекам исходный код загруженной страницы
   WB_GetHTMLCode(Webbrowser1, Memo3.Lines);
   Memo3.Text:=Utf8Decode(Memo3.Text);
   // удаляем лишние теги и код в счете
   Memo2.Lines:=ParseStr(Memo3.Text,'<div  class="cl-left red">','</span>');
   Memo2.Text:=StringReplace(Memo2.Text,'<span class="result-description-part">','',[rfReplaceAll]);
   Memo2.Text:=StringReplace(Memo2.Text,'<img class="sport-icon-image" src=','',[rfReplaceAll]);
   Memo1.Lines:=ParseStr(Memo2.Text,'https:','.png');
   str:=Memo1.Lines[0];
   Memo2.Text:=StringReplace(Memo2.Text,'https:'+str+'.png','',[rfReplaceAll]);
   Memo2.Text:=StringReplace(Memo2.Text,'"','',[rfReplaceAll]);
   Memo2.Text:=StringReplace(Memo2.Text,'/>','',[rfReplaceAll]);
   Memo2.Text:=StringReplace(Memo2.Text,' ','',[rfReplaceAll]);
   Kol:=Memo2.Lines.Count;
end;

// процедура поиска счета
procedure TMainForm.Search;
var i,p: integer;
    str: string;
    found: boolean;
begin
  if Kol<>KolOld then for i:=0 to 1000 do used[i]:=False;
  found:=False;
  for i :=0 to Memo2.Lines.Count-1 do
    begin
      str:=Memo2.Lines[i];
      p:=Pos('('+trim(Edit1.Text),str);
      if p=0 then  p:=Pos('('+trim(Edit3.Text),str);
      // если найден указанный счет в первом сете
      if (p<>0) and (str[p-1]<>')') and (not found) and (NOT Used[i]) then
        begin
          found:=True;
          Timer.Enabled:=False;
          // включаем сигнал и выводим сообщение
          PlaySound(PChar(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+'beep.wav'),0,SND_FILENAME+SND_ASYNC );
          ShowMessage('Такой счет найден! '+Memo2.Lines[i]);
          // после нажатия "Ок" отчключаем сигнализацию
          PlaySound(0, 0, SND_PURGE);
          Used[i]:=True;
          KolOld:=Kol;
          Timer.Enabled:=True;  c v
        end;

    end;
end;

// Обработка таймера
procedure TMainForm.TimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Pars;
   Application.ProcessMessages;
   Search;
   Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

// остановка таймера
procedure TMainForm.BtnStopClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer.Enabled:=False;
end;

// загрузка страницы
procedure TMainForm.BtnLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   Memo3.Clear;
   // грузим страницу в TWebBrowser
   WebBrowser1.Navigate('https://www.marathonbet.com/su/live/22723');
   // ождиаем окончания загрузки страницы
   While WebBrowser1.Busy do Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут программа не работает с новыми окнами. Просто показывает `MessageBox`

Вот это строка

```
ShowMessage('Такой счет найден! '+Memo2.Lines[i]);
```

Вам нужно просто поставить на главную форму `MainForm` один `TListBox` и выводите результаты не `ShowMessage` а

```
ListBox.Add('Такой счет найден! '+Memo2.Lines[i]);
```

у вас будет в одном списке все сообщения.